# Cannot access to Many2Many field

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

For a new custom module, i have added a Many2many field in my model. It seems work but,  I can't access to fields in my view from this Many2many

```
class ouvrage_element(models.Model):
   _name = 'ouvrage.ouvrage_element'
   _description = 'ouvrage_element'

   name = fields.Char(
      string='Nom',
      required=True)

   main_ouvrage = fields.Many2many(
      comodel_name="ouvrage",
      relation="sub_ouvrage",
      column1="main_ouvrage",
      column2="sub_ouvrage_ids")
```

```
class Ouvrage(models.Model):
   _name = 'ouvrage'
   _description = 'Ouvrage'

   name = fields.Char(
      string='Nom',
      help='Nom',
      required=True)

   sub_ouvrage_ids = fields.Many2many(
      comodel_name="ouvrage_element", 
      relation="sub_ouvrage", 
      column1="sub_ouvrage_ids", 
      column2="main_ouvrage")
```

---

```
<record id="view_ouvrage_form" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">ouvrage.form</field>
<field name="model">ouvrage</field>
<field name="type">form</field>
<field name="priority" eval="8"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Ouvrage" version="7.0">
<sheet>
<field name="sub_ouvrage_ids" widget="many2many" string="Sous-ouvrages">
    <tree>
         <field name="name"/>
    </tree>
</field>
</sheet>
</form>
</field>
</record>
```

"File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/models.py", line 1112, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `name` does not exist"

Comment: Check `comodel_name` in `ouvrage` model.

Comment: I was that ! Thank you sooo muuuch :)

Comment: No issue. Happy Coding @Théo Da Silva

Comment: Please submit an answer so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Just an error in the `sub_ouvrage_ids` comodel: `ouvrage_element` instead of `ouvrage.ouvrage_element` 
Thank's to @Rohit-Pandey for the answer